# How do I access maven project version in javadoc overview page?

Tags: maven, pdf, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am using `PDFDoclet` with `maven-javadoc-plugin` and I've come quite a long way with it now. I have the maven and javadoc config almost at a point that is good enough but my immediate problem now is that I can't work out how to push the project version number into the PDF title page.

Before you leap to answer my question by telling me to use maven's `<resource>` filtering, let me outline why that isn't working.

Filtering works by taking the original file from somewhere in the `src` folder, doing variable substitution and putting the output in the `target` folder.

Javadoc works by reading files in `src/main/java` and `src/main/javadoc` and AFAIK outputting the results into `target`. This means filtering is useless for Javadoc since it won't read anything from `target`

My results show that any maven variables in javadoc comments don't get substituted.

What trick can I use to get those variables substituted into the javadoc?

The solution can't involve filtering the javadoc output after the site:site task, unless resource filtering works on PDFs.

This is the configuration, FWIW:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <show>package</show>
      <docfilessubdirs>true</docfilessubdirs>
      <tags>
        <tag>
          <name>pdfInclude</name>
          <placement>X</placement>
          <head></head>
        </tag>
      </tags>
    </configuration>
    <reportSets>
      <reportSet>
        <id>PDF</id>
        <reports>
          <report>javadoc</report>
        </reports>
        <configuration>
          <name>PDF</name>
          <description>PDF doc</description>
          <destDir>pdf</destDir>
          <doclet>com.tarsec.javadoc.pdfdoclet.PDFDoclet</doclet>
          <docletPath>${basedir}/pdfdoclet/pdfdoclet-1.0.3-all.jar</docletPath>
          <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
          <additionalparam>-pdf my_tech_doc-${project.version}.pdf
            -config ${basedir}/pdfdoclet/pdfdoclet.properties</additionalparam>
        </configuration>
      </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
  </plugin>
```

and the `pdfdoclet.properties`:

```
    # http://pdfdoclet.sourceforge.net/configuration.html
    #
    #Lets the doclet print additional output in the console and to a logfile.
    debug=true 
    #Print "Author" tags
    author=false  
    #Print "Version" tags
    version=true
    #Print "since" tags
    tag.since=true
    #Create summary tables
    summary.table=false
    #Create hyperlinks
    create.links=true
    #Encrypt the PDF file
    encrypted=false
    #Allow printing of the PDF file
    allow.printing=true 
    #Create a bookmark frame
    create.frame=true
    #Print a title page
    api.title.page=true
    api.copyright=None
    api.author=Hansruedi
    #Enables the tag-based filter
    filter=true
    filter.tags=pdfInclude
    font.text.name=resources/arial.ttf
    page.orientation=portrait
```

The `PDFDoclet`-specific `api.*` properties should result in a title page as the first page of the PDF, but it doesn't work. If there is a trick that I've missed here and I could get that title page produced, then that might also allow a solution for this somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I can do a quick and dirty hack with the maven `<resources>` functionality:

```
  <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
    <targetPath>${basedir}/src/main/javadoc</targetPath>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>**/overview.html</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
```

This copies my `overview.html` and filters it, outputting it into the `javadoc` source directory.

The dirtiness is that this filtered version could then accidentally end up under version control, although using `svn` I can add it to the `ignore` list.